# How to do HTTPS GET with client certificate in node

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, npm, certificate

I can use curl for making a GET request ->

```
`curl -v https://example.com:82/v1/api?a=b` -E client_cert.pem:password
```

How can I use same in node. I tried request, superagent but not able to pass certificate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**This worked for me** -

```
var https = require('https');
var fs  = require('fs');

var options = {
  hostname: 'example.com',
  port: 83,
  path: '/v1/api?a=b',
  method: 'GET',
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/private-key/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/certificate/client_cert.pem'),  
  passphrase: 'password'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
console.log(res.statusCode);
res.on('data', function(d) {
  process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.end()
```

Comment: What is the `key.pem` file?

Comment: @KingJulien key.pem is private key needed to have authentication with host AFAIR :)

Comment: the private key is not needed for an http request. it is used by the server

Comment: @youneszeboudj it can be used on client when you use a client certificate to authenticate your https request